# How to read a class then a child class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find all the value in a child class using javascript (jquery). I am unable to pinpoint the issue using developer tool. I uploaded the HTML, javascript, and CSS [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9eojdk93/2/)

Just wanted to see what am I missing from my code that it doesn't even trigger the sample alert I have right after the loop of the parent-child code. HTML is here and in the fiddle. the alert should show Cost (1)

```
</tr><tr class="ms-gb" lgrp="1"><td style="padding-left: 0px;" colspan="7"><a href="javascript:"><img id="lt_expandCollapseImage" onclick="_lt_LTGridViewExpandCollapseA(this.parentNode);" alt="Cost" src="/_layouts/15/images/plus.gif" border="0"></a>&nbsp;<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="_lt_LTGridViewExpandCollapseA(this);">Cost (1)</span></td></tr>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ms-listviewtable td[class^='ms-gb']").each(function(){
      var mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-report-category")[0];
      var liTag = document.createElement('li');
      var aTag = document.createElement('a');
      var str = $(this).find("span:last");
      alert(str);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ms-listviewtable .tr[class='ms-gb']").each(function() {
    alert('test');
    var mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-report-category")[0];
    var liTag = document.createElement('li');
    var aTag = document.createElement('a');

    var str = $(this).find("span:last");
    alert(str);
    //var str = $(this).text();
    str = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1); //remove everything before :
    str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("(")); //remove counts

    if (!str.trim() || str.trim() == null) {
      liTag = document.createElement('li');
      aTag = document.createElement('a');
      aTag.innerHTML = "Other";
      var link = window.location.href + "&RC=" + str.trim();
    } else {
      liTag = document.createElement('li');
      aTag = document.createElement('a');
      aTag.innerHTML = str.trim();
      var link = window.location.href + "&RC=" + str.trim();
    }

    aTag.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    aTag.setAttribute("href", link);

    liTag.appendChild(aTag);
    mydiv.appendChild(liTag);
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-report-category {
  border: none !important;
}

.nav-report-category li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(74, 137, 220);
  color: #fff!important;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px;
  font-color: #fff!important;
}

.nav-report-category li.active {
  background-color: #CB6015!important;
  color: #fff!important;
}

.nav-report-category li a:visited {
  color: #fff!important;
}

.nav-report-category li a {
  color: #fff!important;
}

.nav-report-category li:Hover {
  background-color: #BE3A34;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tab-desc {
  background-color: rgb(93, 156, 236);
  color: #fff !important;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tab-desc H2 {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="ms-listviewtable" cellspacing="0" id="ctl00_ctl40_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8__LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay" style="border-style:None;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ms-viewheadertr">
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;"><a onclick="LTGridViewSortColumn_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;DocIcon&quot;);return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl40$g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8$_LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay','Sort$DocIcon')">Type</a><span>&nbsp;</span>
        <img
          src="../_layouts/15/images/FILTER.GIF" title="Configure dynamic filtering for &quot;Type&quot; column" onclick="ConfigureDynamicFiltering_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;DocIcon&quot;);" style="cursor:pointer;"></th>
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;"><a onclick="LTGridViewSortColumn_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;BusinessFunction&quot;);return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl40$g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8$_LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay','Sort$BusinessFunction')">Business Function</a><span>&nbsp;</span>
        <img
          src="../_layouts/15/images/FILTER.GIF" title="Configure dynamic filtering for &quot;Business Function&quot; column" onclick="ConfigureDynamicFiltering_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;BusinessFunction&quot;);" style="cursor:pointer;"></th>
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;"><a onclick="LTGridViewSortColumn_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;ReportCategory&quot;);return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl40$g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8$_LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay','Sort$ReportCategory')">Report Category</a><span>&nbsp;</span>
        <img
          src="../_layouts/15/images/FILTER.GIF" title="Configure dynamic filtering for &quot;Report Category&quot; column" onclick="ConfigureDynamicFiltering_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;ReportCategory&quot;);" style="cursor:pointer;"></th>
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;"><a onclick="LTGridViewSortColumn_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;FileLeafRef&quot;);return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl40$g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8$_LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay','Sort$FileLeafRef')">Name</a></th>
      <th
        class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;"><a onclick="LTGridViewSortColumn_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;Title&quot;);return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl40$g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8$_LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay','Sort$Title')">Title</a><span>&nbsp;</span>
        <img
          src="../_layouts/15/images/FILTER.GIF" title="Configure dynamic filtering for &quot;Title&quot; column" onclick="ConfigureDynamicFiltering_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;Title&quot;);" style="cursor:pointer;"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-gb" lgrp="1">
      <td colspan="7" style="padding-left:0px;">
        <a href="javascript:"><img id="lt_expandCollapseImage" src="/_layouts/15/images/plus.gif" onclick="_lt_LTGridViewExpandCollapseA(this.parentNode);" border="0" alt="Finance"></a>&nbsp;<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="_lt_LTGridViewExpandCollapseA(this);">Finance (9)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;AR Invoice Billing and Receipt History.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl&quot;);"
          href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;AR Invoice Billing and Receipt History.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl&quot;);"
          href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl">AR Invoice Billing and Receipt History.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating" style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Financial Project Report V1.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Financial Project Report V1.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl">Financial Project Report V1.rdl</a></td>
      <td
        class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Financial Project Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Financial Project Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl">Financial Project Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td
        class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating" style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;PA Billing Event Exception Details.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;PA Billing Event Exception Details.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl">PA Billing Event Exception Details.rdl</a></td>
      <td
        class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;PA Expenditure Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;PA Expenditure Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl">PA Expenditure Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td
        class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating" style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Sales Order Detail Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Sales Order Detail Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl">Sales Order Detail Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td
        class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Sales Order Summary Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Sales Order Summary Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl">Sales Order Summary Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td
        class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating" style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;WIP Reconciliation Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;WIP Reconciliation Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl">WIP Reconciliation Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td
        class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;WIP Summary Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;WIP Summary Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl">WIP Summary Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td
        class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-gb" lgrp="1">
      <td colspan="7" style="padding-left:0px;">
        <a href="javascript:"><img id="lt_expandCollapseImage" src="/_layouts/15/images/plus.gif" onclick="_lt_LTGridViewExpandCollapseA(this.parentNode);" border="0" alt="Markview"></a>&nbsp;<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="_lt_LTGridViewExpandCollapseA(this);">Markview (2)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating" style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Markview Hold Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Markview Hold Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Markview</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl">Markview Hold Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td
        class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Markview Queue Rpt.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Markview Queue Rpt.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Markview</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl">Markview Queue Rpt.rdl</a></td>
      <td
        class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing but generally speaking if you want to access a child element using jquery all you have to do is:

    $(".parent").children().val();

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: the code has more line than there are allowed on Stackoverflow @Barmar , i already tried to edit and add snippet here

Comment: Start by deciding between jQuery and vanilla Javascript. You don't need to mix both in your code.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam You don't have to post all the code, just the part that's relevant to the question.

Comment: that is what the OP can decide :)

Comment: I updated and used Stack Snippets. hope it helps everyone. Sorry.

Comment: you added `.ms-listviewtable .tr[class='ms-gb']` in the code it should be `.ms-listviewtable tr[class='ms-gb']` you have an extra `.` before the `tr`

Comment: i updated the answer please check again and confirm. @Fuji-H2O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two minor things:

1. `ms-gb` is on `tr` not on the `td`
2. str is a jQuery object. Change it to `var str = $(this).find("span:last").text()` for the text

Here's the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/9eojdk93/7/)

Comment: The jsFiddle works perfectly. I have no idea why SharePoint is not working. I tried both Chrome and IE and it's same thing. I put this in the console and the count is correct.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: but it's not working in SharePoint. The html i provided is from sharepoint. I can run this in console and the count is good console.log($(".ms-listviewtable tr[class^='ms-gb']").length);

Comment: HTML and jQuery/javascript wise, it seems to provide the said output. I'm not sure if I can help with Sharepoint. I'm guessing some typos or if it isn't easily solvable, that'd be another question.

Comment: Make sure you've included jQuery. I still see "$ is not defined" error in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

your `ms-gb` is on `tr` not on the `td` looking at your fiddle you provided. change it and it will start working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ms-listviewtable tr[class='ms-gb']").each(function() {

    var mydiv = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-report-category")[0];
    var liTag = document.createElement('li');
    var aTag = document.createElement('a');

    var str = $(this).find("span:last").text();
    console.log(str)
    //var str = $(this).text();
    str = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1); //remove everything before :
    str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("(")); //remove counts

    if (!str.trim() || str.trim() == null) {
      liTag = document.createElement('li');
      aTag = document.createElement('a');
      aTag.innerHTML = "Other";
      var link = window.location.href + "&RC=" + str.trim();
    } else {
      liTag = document.createElement('li');
      aTag = document.createElement('a');
      aTag.innerHTML = str.trim();
      var link = window.location.href + "&RC=" + str.trim();
    }

    aTag.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    aTag.setAttribute("href", link);
    console.log(liTag, mydiv);
    liTag.appendChild(aTag);

    mydiv.appendChild(liTag);
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-report-category {
  border: none !important;
}

.nav-report-category li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(74, 137, 220);
  color: #fff!important;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 9px 9px 0px 0px;
  font-color: #fff!important;
}

.nav-report-category li.active {
  background-color: #CB6015!important;
  color: #fff!important;
}

.nav-report-category li a:visited {
  color: #fff!important;
}

.nav-report-category li a {
  color: #fff!important;
}

.nav-report-category li:Hover {
  background-color: #BE3A34;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tab-desc {
  background-color: rgb(93, 156, 236);
  color: #fff !important;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tab-desc H2 {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="ms-listviewtable" cellspacing="0" id="ctl00_ctl40_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8__LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay" style="border-style:None;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ms-viewheadertr">
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;"><a onclick="LTGridViewSortColumn_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;DocIcon&quot;);return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl40$g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8$_LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay','Sort$DocIcon')">Type</a><span>&nbsp;</span>
        <img src="../_layouts/15/images/FILTER.GIF" title="Configure dynamic filtering for &quot;Type&quot; column" onclick="ConfigureDynamicFiltering_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;DocIcon&quot;);" style="cursor:pointer;"></th>
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;"><a onclick="LTGridViewSortColumn_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;BusinessFunction&quot;);return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl40$g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8$_LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay','Sort$BusinessFunction')">Business Function</a><span>&nbsp;</span>
        <img src="../_layouts/15/images/FILTER.GIF" title="Configure dynamic filtering for &quot;Business Function&quot; column" onclick="ConfigureDynamicFiltering_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;BusinessFunction&quot;);" style="cursor:pointer;"></th>
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;"><a onclick="LTGridViewSortColumn_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;ReportCategory&quot;);return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl40$g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8$_LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay','Sort$ReportCategory')">Report Category</a><span>&nbsp;</span>
        <img src="../_layouts/15/images/FILTER.GIF" title="Configure dynamic filtering for &quot;Report Category&quot; column" onclick="ConfigureDynamicFiltering_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;ReportCategory&quot;);" style="cursor:pointer;"></th>
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;"><a onclick="LTGridViewSortColumn_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;FileLeafRef&quot;);return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl40$g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8$_LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay','Sort$FileLeafRef')">Name</a></th>
      <th class="ms-vh2" scope="col" style="text-align:Center;"><a onclick="LTGridViewSortColumn_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;Title&quot;);return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl40$g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8$_LT_GridViewContainerToDisplay','Sort$Title')">Title</a><span>&nbsp;</span>
        <img src="../_layouts/15/images/FILTER.GIF" title="Configure dynamic filtering for &quot;Title&quot; column" onclick="ConfigureDynamicFiltering_webPartUniqueId_g_653c0b92_a010_4d61_bad1_f8584423dda8(&quot;Title&quot;);" style="cursor:pointer;"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-gb" lgrp="1">
      <td colspan="7" style="padding-left:0px;">
        <a href="javascript:"><img id="lt_expandCollapseImage" src="/_layouts/15/images/plus.gif" onclick="_lt_LTGridViewExpandCollapseA(this.parentNode);" border="0" alt="Finance"></a>&nbsp;<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="_lt_LTGridViewExpandCollapseA(this);">Finance (9)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;AR Invoice Billing and Receipt History.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl&quot;);"
          href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;AR Invoice Billing and Receipt History.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl&quot;);"
          href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/AR%20Invoice%20Billing%20and%20Receipt%20History.rdl">AR Invoice Billing and Receipt History.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating" style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Financial Project Report V1.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Financial Project Report V1.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report%20V1.rdl">Financial Project Report V1.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Financial Project Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Financial Project Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Financial%20Project%20Report.rdl">Financial Project Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating" style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;PA Billing Event Exception Details.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;PA Billing Event Exception Details.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/PA%20Billing%20Event%20Exception%20Details.rdl">PA Billing Event Exception Details.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;PA Expenditure Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;PA Expenditure Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/PA%20Expenditure%20Report.rdl">PA Expenditure Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating" style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Sales Order Detail Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Sales Order Detail Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Detail%20Report.rdl">Sales Order Detail Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Sales Order Summary Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Sales Order Summary Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Sales%20Order%20Summary%20Report.rdl">Sales Order Summary Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating" style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;WIP Reconciliation Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;WIP Reconciliation Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/WIP%20Reconciliation%20Report.rdl">WIP Reconciliation Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;WIP Summary Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;WIP Summary Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Finance</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/WIP%20Summary%20Report.rdl">WIP Summary Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-gb" lgrp="1">
      <td colspan="7" style="padding-left:0px;">
        <a href="javascript:"><img id="lt_expandCollapseImage" src="/_layouts/15/images/plus.gif" onclick="_lt_LTGridViewExpandCollapseA(this.parentNode);" border="0" alt="Markview"></a>&nbsp;<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="_lt_LTGridViewExpandCollapseA(this);">Markview (2)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ms-alternating" style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Markview Hold Report.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Markview Hold Report.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Markview</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Markview%20Hold%20Report.rdl">Markview Hold Report.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <td class="ms-vb2" style="width:5px;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="5" height="1" alt=""></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2" align="center" style="width:1px;">
        <a title="Click to open &quot;Markview Queue Rpt.rdl&quot;" onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl"><img title="Click to open &quot;Markview Queue Rpt.rdl&quot;" src="../_layouts/15/images/doc_sp16.gif" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">rdl</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Accounting</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">Markview</td>
      <td class="ms-vb2"><a onclick="DispDocItemExWithServerRedirect(this, event, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;FALSE&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl&quot;); return false;"
          onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this, event, &quot;1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;1https://myanalytix.beta.com/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl&quot;);" href="https://myanalytix.beta.com/SSRSReports/Markview%20Queue%20Rpt.rdl">Markview Queue Rpt.rdl</a></td>
      <td class="ms-vb2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: $(".ms-listviewtable tr[class^='ms-gb']").each(function(){   still not working but i will play with it

Comment: try adding external jquery resource in your fiddle and add `console.log($(".ms-listviewtable tr[class^='ms-gb']").length);` after document ready , it gives me count `16` , i think it works and should enter the `.each()` function now.

Comment: Muhammad: I get an error when i click on "Run code snippet" {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: str.indexOf is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 238,
  "colno": 29

Comment: that would be related to some other thing but it is entering the .each now arent you getting the alert ?

Comment: `str = str.substring(str.indexOf(":") + 1)` this is the line triggering the error which means `str` isnt a valid string check in console if it is printing a valid string and not an object

Comment: just noticed that you have this statement before you call `indexOf` , `var str = $(this).find("span:last");` shouldnt you add `.text()` in the end

Comment: just revised the code it is working now, only one thing your variable `mydiv` that gets object of the element with class `.nav-report-category` is missing from the `HTML` add it and it will work @Fuji-H2O

Comment: mydiv is already in the code https://jsfiddle.net/9eojdk93/8/ . I can't get this work in SharePoint

Comment: that is because you havent added jquery in the external resources in your fiddle , try adding a CDN link to jquery and it will work i just tested it

Comment: jquery reference is already added in SharePoint to this file as <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> https://jsfiddle.net/9eojdk93/10/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing but generally speaking if you want to access a child element using jquery all you have to do is:

```
<div class="primary">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".primary").click(function(){
            $(this).children().each(function(){

            });

        });
    });
```